# Java RMI connection between clients

Tags: java, rmi

I try to make a simple RMI application, which connect two clients(Bramka,Monitor) with server(Centrala), and client_1(Bramka) with client_2(Monitor)

Bramka.class

```
public class Bramka extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IBramka{

    protected Bramka() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "//localhost:1099/RMI";
        try{
            ICentrala c = (ICentrala) Naming.lookup(url);
            c.getZarejestrowaneBramki();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean test() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.print("Something from client1");
    }


}
```

Centrala.class:

```
public class Centrala extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ICentrala {


    protected Centrala() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "//localhost:1099/RMI";
        try {
            Centrala centrala = new Centrala();
            Naming.rebind(url,centrala);
            System.out.println("centrala wystartowala");
        }catch (Exception e ) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void getZarejestrowaneBramki() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Something from server");

    }


}
```

Monitor.class

```
public class Monitor extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IMonitor{


    protected Monitor() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "//localhost:1099/RMI";
        try{
            ICentrala c = (ICentrala) Naming.lookup(url);
            IBramka b = (IBramka) Naming.lookup(url); //error
            c.getZarejestrowaneBramki();
            b.test();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void koniecznaAktualizacja() throws RemoteException {

    }

}
```

What i want to do is run method `test` from `Bramka` client in `Monitor` client. If i try to do that, i get Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to IBramka
```

If i want to run method from `Centrala` it works fine. Some tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
ICentrala c = (ICentrala) Naming.lookup(url);
IBramka b = (IBramka)Naming.lookup(url);
```

This doesn't make sense. You are looking up the same URL twice and expecting to be able to cast it to two different remote interfaces. You need *two* URLs, and you also need `Bramka` to bind itself to the Registry under the second URL.

Another thing that doesn't make sense is your terminology. These are both *servers*.